# How do I remove introduction movies in games based on the Unreal Engine 3?

Tags: borderlands, batman-arkham-asylum

Games like Borderlands, Batman Arkham Asylum or in general games based on the Unreal Engine 3 have introduction movies with the publisher logo, the graphical card provider, etc, that you can or not skip.

How can I do so that they don't play at the beginning, and I can access the main menu faster?

Comment: What about the New game bus video of Borderlands?

Comment: @Alexander - it's a different case, you should probably ask this is a separate question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll want to find the `UTEngine.ini` which is usually in `path\to\game\Config` and add a `;` in front of every StartupMovies declaration.

For example, for UT3:

```
;StartupMovies=Copyright_PC
;StartupMovies=EpicLogo
;StartupMovies=MidwayLogo
```

et cetera.